# Form validation not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use some code from a form validation example and tailor it to my own form but it doesn't seem to be working. There is a message that is supposed to appear when a user enters a name,phone number or email incorrectly e.g 'please enter a valid name'.I don't understand javascript that well so am struggling to try and find the problem. There aren't any console problems if that helps it is probably a naming issue?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uwS3/)**

HTML

```
  <form>
  <div class="formColumn2">

    <label for="name">
    <span class="textStyle">Full Name*</span><input type="text" id="name"><br>
    <span id="nameMessage" class="message">You must have a valid name</span>
    </label>

    <label for="email"><span class="textStyle">Email*</span>
    <input type="text" id="email"><br>
    <span id="emailMessage" class="message">You must have a valid email</span>
    </label>

    <label for="phoneNumber">
    <span class="textStyle">Phone Number*</span>
    <input type="text" id="phoneNumber"><br>
    <span id="phoneMessage" class="message">You must have a valid phone number</span>
    </label>

      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

 </div>
     </form>
```

CSS

```
.textStyle {
width: 150px;
display: inline-block;
}

.formColumn2 {
margin-top:-80px;
margin-left: 50px;
}

select{
width:200px;
margin:10px 0;
}


input[type=text],
input[type=password]{
width:200px;
margin:10px 0;
}


.message{
display: none;  
}

input[type=submit]{
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid black;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=text].error,
input[type=password].error{
border: 3px solid red;
color: red; 
}
```

Javascript

```
var nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
var emailInput = document.querySelector('#email');
var phoneInput = document.querySelector ('#phoneNumber');

function displayError(fieldname, message) {
    var input_field = document.querySelector('#' + fieldname);
    var error_box = document.querySelector('#' + fieldname + 'Message');

    addClass (input_field, 'error');

    error_box.style.display = 'block';
    error_box.innerHTML = message;

}

function hideError(fieldname){
    var input_field = document.querySelector('#'+fieldname);
    var error_box = document.querySelector('#'+fieldname+'Message');
    removeClass (input_field, 'error');
    error_box.style.display = 'none';
}

function addClass(html_element,class_str) {
    if(html_element.className.indexOf(class_str) == -1){
        html_element.className += ' '+class_str;
    }
}

function removeClass(html_element, class_str){
    if(html_element.className.indexOf(class_str) != -1){
        html_element.className = html_element.className.replace(class_str, '');
    }
}

nameInput.onblur = function(){
    if(!nameInput.value){
        valid = false;
        displayError('name', 'Please enter your name'); 
    }else if(!isValidName(nameInput.value)){
        valid = false;
        displayError('name', 'That name has invalid characters');
    }else{
        hideError('name');
    }

    emailInput.onblur = function(){
    if(!emailInput.value){
        valid = false;
        displayError('email', 'Please enter your email');
    }else if(!isValidEmail(emailInput.value)){
        valid = false;
        displayError('email', 'The email field is invalid');
    }else{
        hideError('email');
    }
}

phoneInput.onblur = function(){
    if(!emailInput.value){
        valid = false;
        displayError('phone', 'Please enter your number');
    }else if(!isValidEmail(emailInput.value)){
        valid = false;
        displayError('email', 'The phone number field is invalid');
    }else{
        hideError('phone');
    }
}

submitButton.onclick = function(){

    var valid = true;

    return valid;
}

function isValidName(str){
    var namePattern = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z \s\'-]{1,}$');

    return namePattern.test(str);
}

function isValidEmail(str) { 
    var emailPattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return emailPattern.test(str);
}
```

Comment: your fiddle as an error **unexpected end of input** check once

Comment: You missed the closing `}` for the `nameInput.onblur` handler, check this udpated demo http://jsfiddle.net/HNSM4/1/

Comment: Too many errors - submitButton not defined, missing bracket (}) etc, etc...

Comment: how would I be able to validate the phone Number input? I just want to use the same function as the name input.I have the error message set up in the html

Comment: @ev9604 you can add more a function to validate the phone number (such as call it `isValidPhoneNumber`), validating the phone number depends much on the phone number format used in your country. In this demo, I just supposed a valid phone number should have 10 to 13 digits (lesser than 10 or greater than 13 is considered to be invalid). Then modify the `phoneInput.onblur` handler accordingly (which is very similar to other handlers) http://jsfiddle.net/HNSM4/2/

Comment: How would I make the message display? I used the same reg expression as name but its not displaying message like others. have I missed something? http://jsfiddle.net/HNSM4/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you will use jQuery, it will be less complicated.

if that you need to use

```
$('.formClass').validate();
```

and in html
just put `required` in text fields, whom you want they not to be  empty.

```
<form class="formCLass">
    <input type="text" name="username" required/>
        <input type="email" name="email" required/>
</form>
```